# Matching multiline regex in Sublime Text

Tags: regex, sublimetext3

I was tried to write regex in Sublime Text that find three match in

```
A1
A2
A3
B1
B2
B3
C1
C2
C3
```

1 match

```
A1
A2
A3
```

2 match

```
B1
B2
B3
```

3 match

```
C1
C2
C3
```

Of course, It can be handled with for example

```
((?:A\d\n)+|(?:B\d\n)+|(?:C\d\n)+)
```

Is there more smart approach to do it instead of just enumerating?

[Interactive demo](https://regex101.com/r/yalhNb/2)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use

```
^([A-Z])\d+(?:\R\1\d+)*
```

See the [PCRE regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qnxbTJ/1) (SublimeText3 uses PCRE regex engine).

**Details**

- `^` - start of a line
- `([A-Z])` - Group 1: any ASCII uppercase letter (just note that if *Case sensitive* option is off, this will also match lowercase letters)
- `\d+` - 1+ digits
- `(?:\R\1\d+)*` - zero or more repetitions of:

  - `\R` - a line break
  - `\1` - the same letter as in Group 1
  - `\d+` - 1+ digits

Answer (score 1):

Try this pattern: `([A-Z])\d\n\1\d\n\1\d`.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/mTlA1I/1)